# How to reference a file from Mylyn's Jenkins-View?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, mylyn

we use Eclipse + Mylyn + Trac-Integration + Jenkins/Hudson-Integration + Subversive and for the most part, everything works well. If I work on a task, change stuff, commit it into the subversion with the auto-generated comment from Mylyn and have it built on Jenkins, it is allright.

When I now open the build in the Jenkins-View within Eclipse, I have the "Changes"-part in the window. Within there, I can see all changes which have been considered in that build, compared to the previous one. I can even doubleclick on one changeset and the connected task pops up.

BUT: If I want to open a changed file from that view, I only get "The selected file is not available in the workspace".

Please see the image for the exact location of the problem.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Any idea, where something might be amiss?

Thanks!

Dominik

Comment: I just realised that the image is quite small/downscaled. If a bigger version is needed, I'll try to upload one to some imagehoster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, opening changed files from the build is not yet supported for SVN.

Comment: Thanks, then I can stop looking for the correct setup ;-) Any chance this is going to be implemented eventually?